# HTML setting an HTML page on load

Tags: html

I've just got my website up and when I only type in the domain I get an Index of all the files that I've uploaded, but I want it to load my HTML page when it gets loaded as **www.domain.com/domain.html**  instead  I want it to be **www.domain.com**.

How do I do this? Do I have to contact my hosters or can I do this in the project?

Comment: This has to be set on server level, not in your html files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the web server doesn't use wacky configuration, you can just name the main file "index.html" and it will be the main access point to your domain.

Comment: Just did that and it works perfectly! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep index.html file in top level directory of application. If you do not have index.html file then add new file in top level directory and redirect it using onLoad function to your website home page.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to rename `domain.html` to `index.html` and it will be displayed automatically when the site loads.

That is the main page you wish to display when someone visits `www.domain.com` should be named `index.html` if it is an `html` page, if not you use the correct file extension.

Answer (score 0):

A way to keep using domain.html as the main source file. Create an index.html file and add the following code in it.

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
       window.location='domain.html';
    }, 5000);
</script>
```